# Line length in JAVA

Tags: java

i have question about restrictions or conventions in Java. Is there any restriction concerning to maximal length of  line code in java? Or can very long lines cause any problems?

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-136091.html#313

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no relevant limit to Java line lengths, the compiler might have one, but it is probably in the range of several KBs. However, this is not very practical. I tend to keep my lines below 100 characters.

Older documentation might say 80, but I think that is no longer practical, because almost no one prints code anymore and usually screens show more than 80 columns at a time.

As for the conventions, yes, there are some. See the Java documentation for that. It also talks about the usual placement of linebreaks, braces etc.

Here is a link: [Java Coding Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html)

Comment: Having more than 80 columns per line interferes with having several files open, side-by-side, on the same screen…

Comment: That is very much dependent on font size, screen resolution, soft-wrap and a number of other factors. Anyway, having *very* long lines is often a sign of bad coding style anyway.

Answer (score 2):

See [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) for Java conventions by Oracle. 
In this they say a line should contain 80 Characters maximum.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, but it's a good habit if the line fits in screen. It helps debugging and analysing code, and auto-wrap doesn't make good-looking code in most cases.

Some schools learns to avoid writing more than 80 lines of code (to fit it in a console window), but it's not practical in use.

Answer (score 1):

Actually very long classes may cause to an internal memory heap overflow, then you have to increase your heap size , other than that no.